# Countdown timer for pygame

Tags: python, pygame, pacman

I asked a question earlier about a multiple collision detection but I don't have the skill to create code to fix that problem instead I am just adding a second wall and trying to put in a timer.

My question is how do I put a timer into my code?

It needs to count down and when it hits `00:00` show the text: `GAME OVER` and end the game. I am putting in the main line of my code if that helps. If you need more code such as classes etc. I am happy to post it.

```
while done == False:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

            #This makes the player move
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                player.changespeed(-6,0)
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player.changespeed(6,0)
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                player.changespeed(0,-6)
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                player.changespeed(0,6)

        #This stops the player from moving
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                player.changespeed(6,0)
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player.changespeed(-6,0)
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                player.changespeed(0,6)
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                player.changespeed(0,-6)

    player.updateWall(wall_list)

    window.fill(black)

    movingsprt.draw(window)
    wall_list.draw(window)

    pygame.display.flip()

    clock.tick(40)

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 2):

Like Hans Then said, you can use the `pygame.time.set_timer()` method to call a function after a specific amount of time has passed. But in terms of showing how much time has passed you are probably better off using another method.

Using the `pygame.time.Clock.tick_busy_loop` method, you can controll how many FPS your game runs at and track how much time has gone by, since it returns how many millisecons have passed since the last call:

```
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
minutes = 0
seconds = 0
milliseconds = 0

while True: #game loop
    #do stuff here
    if milliseconds > 1000:
        seconds += 1
        milliseconds -= 1000
    if seconds > 60:
        minutes += 1
        seconds -= 60

    print ("{}:{}".format(minutes, seconds))

    milliseconds += clock.tick_busy_loop(60) #returns the time since the last time we called the function, and limits the frame rate to 60FPS
```

Answer (score 1):

You can generate an event after some time. See: http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.set_timer

Using code similar to the one you have now, you can see if the event is a timer event and act accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this

```
time = 100 #time in seconds
pygame.time.set_timer(USEREVENT+1, 1000)#1 second is 1000 milliseconds 

#everything below this line should be in your main loop
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type = USEREVENT+1:
        time -= 1

if time == 0:
    print "GAME OVER"
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you found your answer or, for that matter, if this will be helpful... I, too am working on adding a timer to a game, but I also have some questions... for starters, I am having success with the following code. (I got this from another message board, but I can't seem to find it again so I apologize for not giving credit at this time - I will edit this post when I find the site).

I took this code which was written to display the count in the console window and modified it to show on screen.

I had little success with timer and ticks (for some reason it seemed like my program was running an infinite loop... anyhow:

This is what I'm using:

```
import time
import threading
import pygame, sys
#among others....

#timer clock
global timerrun #I added this to show / hide the clock from my main screen
timerrun = 0 #just a default 

class Timer (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,seconds):
        self.runTime = seconds
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    def run(self):
        time.sleep(self.runTime)

class CountDownTimer(Timer):
    def run(self):
            counter = self.runTime
            for sec in range(self.runTime):
                global timerrun
                timerrun = 1 #set timer is running global variable - tells main loop to display clock
                global timedisp #set timedisplay as global var so it can be shared between threads
                timedisp = clockfont.render(str(counter),1,(255,255,255))
                #print str(counter)
                time.sleep(1.0)
                counter -= 1

class CountDownExec(CountDownTimer):
        def __init__(self, seconds, action):
            self.action = action
            CountDownTimer.__init__(self, seconds)
        def run (self):
            CountDownTimer.run(self)
            self.action()

def myAction():
    #print "Perform an action here... say GAME OVER!"
    global timedisp
    timedisp = clockfont.render("GAME OVER",1,(255,255,255))

c = CountDownExec(timeonclock,myAction)
```

Some caveats:
Firstly, I'm not 100% sure what all of this does... essentially, the first part sets up a timer function.  The second part setups the timer's variables (the count and the delay... for now, I am using 1 second increments for simplicity.)

The next part (I think) tells this function to run inside of a new Thread - so it is running independently from my main loop at it's own pace (ie, it is not pausing my game 1 second at a time)

The last part is what I want to happen when the clock hits zero... I re-set the global timedisp variable to say "GAME OVER"

ALso, I have no idea how taxing this method is on the system.  I have no idea if this is "efficient or not" - I'd love someone's input on this.

Before these functions, I have the font defined as:

```
clockfont = pygame.font.SysFont("#FONT_NAME",SIZE) #font to use for timer clock
```

In my main loop, I am displaying the result with:

```
if timerrun == 1:
        clockpos = (screenwidth - timedisp.get_width()) /2 #center my clock
        screen.blit(timedisp,(clockpos,100)) #put it on screen
```

Again, I am using the timerrun variable because I want the clock (in my game) to be optional... for testing, the clock won't show until you press the "t" key on the keyboard.. 
which executes the timer in a new thread:

```
    if event.key==K_t:
        c.start();
```

It will then display the clock, count down, and then show "GAME OVER" when finished.

Here are MY questions if anyone can help...

I am not sure if passing the changing text via global variable is the "Right" way to do this.. can anyone tell me if / how might be a better way to update the display on screen using these 2 threads.

I would like the action that happens when the time is up (the part that displays "Game Over" - to execute some functions back in the main thread (am I saying this right?)

For instance: when time runs out, it runs a function that compares 2 player's scores and declares a winner. - How can I make "thread 2" (the timer) call a function back in "thread 1" (the rest of the game)??

Lastly, I a looking for a way to "Reset" the clock without resetting the whole program.  When I press "t" again, I get an error that you can't start a thread over again.  Can anyone offer a suggestion on how to restart my clock??

Thank you very much!

Jay